Let $G$ be a simple graph with $2n$ vertices and $n^2+1$ edges. Show that this graph $G$ contains $n$ triangle.
There are various version of problem statements, this is the classical one which I can solve using induction

Let $G$ be a simple graph with $2n$ vertices and $n^2+1$ edges. Show that this graph $G$ contains a triangle.

However the following variants are unclear for me

Let $G$ be a simple graph with $2n$ vertices and $n^2+1$ edges. Show that this graph $G$ contains $n$ triangle.

Another different variant is the below from China TST $1987$

Let $G$ be a simple graph with $2n$ vertices and $n^2+1$ edges. Show that this graph $G$ contains a two triangles with a common edge.


Prove that in every simple graph with $2n$ vertices and $n^2+1$ edges $(n ≥ 3)$ there
exist four vertices which are connected with each other by at least five edges.

The last two are equivalent. Any idea how to attack it?

If there are 4 vertices connected by exactly 5 edges, that's 2 triangles with a common edge.

Can you use the $n=2$ case (four vertices) as the base case for an induction?

@CalvinLin Thank you for pointing out the similar problem. It gave me some idea to attack the last part of my problem, leaving the second part which is there are n triangles. However I am not quite sure with the part where after we delete the 3 vertices and their incident edges, why it guarantee another triangle

This is Mantel's theorem, which states that if the number of edges on a graph of $n$ vertices is more than $n^2/4$ then it has a triangle. It's clear that replacing $n$ by $2n$ gives the result you want, so we just need to prove Mantel's theorem.
Well prove by induction that if $G$ has $n$ vertices and no triangles, then $e(G)\leq n^2/4$. The cases for $n=1,2$ are trivial. Suppose now $G$ has $n+2$ vertices, then, if it has no edges we're done. If it has at least one edge, let $uv$ be an edge. Consider the graph $G'=G-\{u,v\}$. $G'$ has $n$ vertices, no triangles, and so it has at most $n^2/4$ edges. Besides that, since no vertex in $G'$ can be neighbor of both $u$ and $v$ (since that would be a triangle), we know $e(uv,G')\leq n$, putting all this together, we know
\begin{align}e(G)&=1+e(uv,G')+e(G')\\\\&\leq 1+n+\frac{n^2}4\\\\&=\frac{(n+2)^2}4\end{align}
As we wanted, this completes the induction an the proof; of course you could've done the induction directly tailored to your problem, and you would've proved something only slightly weaker, but enough for the problem; but I thought that since the proof was the same, maybe it was a good idea to prove Mantel. Try and adapt the proof to prove Turán's theorem, namely, if $G$ has $n$ vertices and
$$e(G)>\left(1-\frac1r+\frac1n\right)\frac{n^2}2$$
then it contains a $K_{r+1}$ as a subgraph

Also, as Calvin pointed out, their linked question shows how to go from Mantel's theorem to the last two variants you showed
